# Setting label text in listview control in loggedin template

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to set a label text which is listview and the listview is in Logged in template.
I am unable to set the value of the label. Here is the below code.

```
ListView ListView1 = (ListView)LoginView.FindControl("ListView1");

for (int i = 0; i < ListView1.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    Label someLabel = (Label)ListView1.Controls[i].FindControl("nItemsId");
    if (someLabel != null)
        someLabel.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you need to use [ListView.ItemCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcreated.aspx) Event to achieve this

```
protected void LV_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Retrieve the current item.
   ListViewItem item = e.Item;

  // Verify if the item is a data item.
  if (item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
  {
    Label someLabel = (Label)ListView1.Controls[i].FindControl("nItemsId");
    if (someLabel != null)
        someLabel.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
  }
}
```

To use it change your markup to declared the eventHandler like this.

```
<asp:ListView OnItemCreated="LV_ItemCreated" />
```

Comment: When you will bind your list view on Page_Load. This event will automatically fired for creating the items in listview.

Comment: Yeah, However I have another method  protected void On_Select_Item(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e){}. I need to call the above method which you suggested from this method..How can I send ListViewItemEventArgs argument?

Comment: you don't need to call this handler inside of another handler. This handler will take of everything when Item_Created in ListView. We have defined here what should it do when items being created inside them

Comment: I Binded the SQL data to the ListView and have some buttons  in each row, whenever a button is clicked  On_Select_Item is Called and then I need to update a label which is in the Layout Template.

Comment: So you can do the same thing on Select_Item event handler. Find control in that handler and set the value.